# NullPointerException on ViewBinding when return on firestore addSnapshotListener

Tags: kotlin, android-fragments, google-cloud-firestore, kotlin-coroutines, android-viewbinding

I use Viewbinding on my app like google recommends I setup it on fragment onCreateView and attach it to null onDestroyView and it works fine when I go from fragment A to fragment B and click on back button on fragment B then I get back to fragment A successfully but in other case I got NullPointerException on access viewbinding views let me explain this case:

I use firestore on Fragment B to add some data and after the adding process done I close fragment B by this method

```
   private fun saveItem(item: Item) = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
        try {
            itemCollectionRef.add(item).await()
            withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                findNavController().popBackStack()
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
           
        }
    }
```

and on Fragment A there was a method which subscribe to realtime updates and here it is

```
 private fun subscribeToRealtimeUpdates() {
        itemCollectionRef.addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, firebaseFirestoreException ->
            firebaseFirestoreException?.let {
                Toast.makeText(requireActivity(), it.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                return@addSnapshotListener
            }
            val itemList: MutableList<Item> = mutableListOf()
            querySnapshot?.let {

                for (document in it) {
                    val item = document.toObject<Item>()
                    itemList.add(item)

                }
                if (itemList.isNotEmpty()) {
                    binding.loading.visibility = View.GONE // here the error 
                 
               
            }
        }
    }
    }
```

I call subscribeToRealtimeUpdates methon on Fragment onViewCreated and it works fine on first loading and on back from fragment B but it gives this error only on saving item on firestore.

when I comment onDestroyView the error is gone but I know this a bad practice and it may cause memory leaks

```
override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
    }
```

here the whole error message

```
   java.lang.NullPointerException
        at FragmentA.getBinding(FragmentA.kt:34)
        at FragmentA.subscribeToRealtimeUpdates$lambda-3(FragmentA.kt:88)
        at FragmentA.lambda$RZjDeyOAZ3ZuXemIa8YOAw1hzG8(Unknown Source:0)
        at package.-$$Lambda$FragmentA$RZjDeyOAZ3ZuXemIa8YOAw1hzG8.onEvent(Unknown Source:4)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.Query.lambda$addSnapshotListenerInternal$2$Query(Query.java:1133)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.-$$Lambda$Query$JWhMgzcsIac1Z-exZj1pTDRisJg.onEvent(Unknown Source:6)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.AsyncEventListener.lambda$onEvent$0$AsyncEventListener(AsyncEventListener.java:42)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.-$$Lambda$AsyncEventListener$DNkggu2LY54oguDvcp-QtRg6Sfg.run(Unknown Source:6)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7397)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:935)
```

line 34 of error     `private val binding get() = _binding!!`
line 88 of error     `binding.loading.visibility = View.GONE`

so any solution about this error other not destroying viewbinding object on fragment OnDestroyView

Comment: have you found any solution for this

Comment: @JarinRocks not yet you can start bounty on my question to take more attention to it